# What is the difference between “tio” and “ke”?

Tags: esperanto-speakers

Can someone please explain to me, what the difference between the two words *tio* and *ke* is? 
They both translate as *that*, but I assume that like the words *de* and *da* they are used differently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Tio* is a noun-like word, whereas *ke* is a conjunction. More specifically, *tio* translates "that [thing]", and is comparable with other noun-like correlatives (*kio* "what [thing]", *ĉio* "everything", *nenio* "nothing", etc.) and with other indicative correlatives (tia "such/that kind of", tiom "that much", tiam "then/that time"). *Ke* on the other hand is used to connect dependant clauses, ex. *Mi diris **ke** li iris for* for "I said **that** he went away"

Answer (score 2):

Yasmine's answer is great. The following terms help me.

*Tio* is a **deictic** element. That is, it points to something. What thing? "That" thing.

*ke* on the other hand is a **complementizer**. It's only function is to initiate a complement clause. See *Plena Manlibro de Esperanta Gramatiko* §33.2 which reads, "La vorteto *ke* ne vere montras ian signifon. Ĝi nur montras la komencon de subfrazo, kiu ne havas alian frazenkondukilon. *Ke*-frazo povas roli en multaj diversaj frazroloj."

In English, "that" happens to serve both functions. In many other languages, a different word is used for each function. Hope this helps.